# Crear repertorio en computador local usando aplicación web

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

Tengo una aplicación web hecha en .aspx. El código que se encuentra atrás esta hecho en C#.

Mi aplicación funciona bien, uno de los objetivos es crear un repertorio en la computadora local dependiendo de que usuario la ejecute a partir del navegador de internet deseado.

La aplicación ya esta publicada en IIS, pero no encuentro la forma de crear este repertorio.

Estoy usando `Directory.CreateDirectory` pero el repertorio solo se crea localmente (donde esta instalada la aplicacion web)

De que forma podría lograr esto?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ¿Por *Repertorio en la computadora local*, te refieres al dispositivo cliente dónde se ejecuta el browser?. Es necesaria la aclaración, pues para una aplicación web, en realidad la *computadora local* es el servidor dónde se ejecuta.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría hacer esta aplicación en dos partes: Un servicio web que sirve el repertorio por medio de un API REST y un cliente que sea una aplicacion universal de Windows que baje este repertorio cuando este disponible, lo salve en el folder que sea deseado y haga lo que sea necesario con el mismo en la máquina local. Esto no es una respuesta a tu pregunta, solo una sugerencia de arquitectura, por eso lo pongo como un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de un desarrollo web en donde el codigo .net ejecuta del lado del servidor, por temas de seguridad no puedes crear archivos o carpetas en la pc del cliente ya que esto seria una vulnerabilidad del browser si pudieras hacerlo.

Creo que deberías replantear lo que intentas lograr ya que crear algo en los recursos del cliente no se puede, no al menos desde la misma aplicacion web.

Quizas podrias enviar el archivo al cliente y al abrirse el dialogo de descarga permita al usuario seleccionar donde guardarlo, pero se requiere siempre confirmación del usuario.

---

Podrías acceder a los recursos de la pc del usuario, pero deberías implementarlo con código `javascript`, lo cual no se aconseja ya que este tipo de operación son consideradas como malisiosas.

[Javascript FSO CreateFolder Method](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-FSO-CreateFolder-Method.aspx)

Se crea una instancia de

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

**>>De que forma podria cambiar el codigo para darle la opcion de descargarlo preguntandole donde hacerlo?**

Para enviar un archivo debes escribir este en el Response

[ASP.NET: Downloading a DataTable in CSV Format](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926121919/http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/01/29/asp.net-downloading-a-datatable-in-csv-format.aspx)

veras que en el artículo usa

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

 //generas el archivo

 Response.WriteFile("ruta csv");

 Response.End();
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Tienes toda la razon en relacion a la seguridad del cliente. De que forma podria cambiar el codigo para darle la opcion de descargarlo preguntandole donde hacerlo? gracias nuevamente

Comment: @Aarancibia Que tipo de archivo enviarias al cliente?

Comment: seria un archivo .CSV